# restore console generic display driver on Ubuntu server (no GUI)

Tags: 14.04, server, graphics

Since upgrade to 14.04 I have lost my console VGA display output on my Ubuntu server (no GUI).

My system is a NAS server based on Atom D2700 processor. Unfortunately this processor has a GMA 3600 graphic chipset that is not Intel but PowerVR SGX 545.
There is a binary proprietary Linux driver for this chipset that was running fine when I was running Ubuntu 12.04 but it seems it does not work on 14.04.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Except this console problem, the rest of the server is working fine: I can access it through ssh but I want to recover my console display output in case I have a network configuration problem.

I am looking for a solution to get a basic console output (no need for GUI graphic acceleration) as we can usually find on Linux boot CDs or USB keys (CloneZilla, ...)

Is there an easy way to configure my system so it uses a basic generic universal VGA driver?
Thanks

```
0:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0be2] (rev 09) 
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:0be2] 
Kernel driver in use: gma500 
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)
```

Comment: ...and what is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA`?

Comment: @mikewhatever Hello,This gives the following output: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0be2] (rev 09) Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:0be2] Kernel driver in use: gma500 00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution from this useful and clear thread : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250571

It was quite simple: just blacklist the gma500_gfx failing driver.

This can be done at boot during GRUB menu, press '**e**' for edit, edit the `linux` line, add `modprobe.blacklist=gma500_gfx` at end of line just after `ro`

If you want to permanently blacklist this driver edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add the following line:

> `blacklist gma500_gfx`